# mod_rewrite reaches LimitInternalRecursion

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a VServer where i have some admin-apps in /var/www/,
an other common stuff in /var/customers/webs/web001/.

I want to make a redirection for all not existing files and directories

```
            /var/www/ -> /var/customers/webs/web001/
```

So that i can use the domain-name for root and for web001 customer.

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.
I tried with mod_rewrite, but there are internal redirections that reach the Limit of Recursion.

What i am doing wrong?

.htaccess

```
            # allow psydo-location (not existing folder)
            Options +FollowSymLinks

            # Turn on URL rewriting engine
            RewriteEngine On

            # Folder of this htaccess-file in not root-folder
            RewriteBase /var/www/

            # Disable rewriting for existing files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/var/customers/webs/web001/

            # redirect all other requests to index.php
            rewriteRule ^.*$ /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php [DPI,L]
```

apache2/error.log

```
            Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects 
            due to probable configuration error. 
            Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. 
            Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
            redirected from r->uri = /index.php
```

rewrite.log

```
            (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/index.php -> index.php
            (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
            (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/index.php' pattern='!-f' => matched
            (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/index.php' pattern='!-d' => matched
            (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/index.php' pattern='!^/var/customers/webs/web001/' => matched
            (2) [perdir /var/www/] rewrite 'index.php' -> '/var/customers/webs/web001/index.php'
            (2) [perdir /var/www/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/ with /var/www/
            (1) [perdir /var/www/] internal redirect with /var/customers/webs/web001/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
            (3) [perdir /var/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/var -> /var/www/var/customers/webs/web001/index.php
```

Comment: RewriteBase should be relative to the document-root, not to the filesystem root. So it should be just `RewriteBase /`. Also you can't redirect to files outside the DocumentRoot as Apache won't allow it.

Comment: Then my question should be: Where and what should i adjust in order to get the content of the filesystem folders "/var/www/" and "/var/customers/webs/web001/" by request for the same domain?

Comment: It is possible to access files outside of DocumentRoot by setting in httpd.conf the Alias-Directive: Alias /web001 "/var/customers/webs/web001/". Its not exact the same what i want, but is the closest solution, that i got until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found a Solution.
It is not in the .htaccess, but in the httpd.conf.
With appropriate settings for DocumentRoot almost all request will be delivered form /var/customers/webs/web001/, 
except of these who will be excluded with Alias-Directives.

The /etc/apache2/httpd.conf look something like that:

```
            #NameVirtualHost SERVER_IP:PORT
            <VirtualHost SERVER_IP:PORT>
                ServerName SERVER_IP
                ServerAlias DOMAIN.TLD

                # instead of DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
                DocumentRoot "/var/customers/webs/web001/"

                # add Aliases for each Application in the /var/www
                Alias /URL_SUB_PATH_APP_1 "/var/www/URL_SUB_PATH_APP_1"
                Alias /URL_SUB_PATH_APP_2 "/var/www/URL_SUB_PATH_APP_2"
            </VirtualHost>

            Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.conf
```

Like Gerben said, the .htaccess-file is for this purpose not helpful.